# Hide by default typescript errors on browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, vite

I'm using React, Vite, and TypeScript. During development, I encounter TypeScript errors which are displayed on the browser screen.(screenshot) I am aware of these errors and I want to hide the popups with errors by default, without having to click on the close button in the bottom left corner every time.
[image]

I checked ts options and didn't find anything related to it

Comment: Hi! Please post code, error messages, console output, markup, data, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Are you using an online dev environment? Normally, you don't ship TypeScript code to the browser at all, you compile it to JavaScript on your build machine, then deliver the JavaScript to the browser. So unless you're actually running the TypeScript compiler in the browser when your *users* use your site, you don't have to worry about TypeScript errors/warnings appearing in the browser.

Comment: Or, sorry, are you asking how to ignore these errors *at development time*?